# Generating strings from a list of formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a df of names like so:

```
name                first_name middle_name last_name
John Doe            John       D           Doe
Richard Cohen       Richard    NaN         Cohen
Molly Claire Smith  Molly      Claire      Smith
```

and a list of username style formats like this:

```
first_name+last_name
first_initial+last_name
first_initial+last_initial
first_name+last_initial
```

Is there a more elegant way to generate all possible usernames for each person other than:
`df['user1']=('first_name'+'last_name)` and so on to get output that looks something like this:

```
name                first_name middle_name last_name permutation1 permutation2 permutation3 ...
John Doe            John       D           Doe       JohnDoe      JD           JDoe 
Richard Cohen       Richard    NaN         Cohen     RichardCohen RC           RCohen
Molly Claire Smith  Molly      Claire      Smith     MollySmith   MS           MSmith
```

Comment: Could you provide an example with an input and desired output?

Comment: how do you want the formats? a column of lists?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do using a custom function in [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def gen_username(row):
    u1 = row['first_name'] + '_' + row['last_name']
    u2 = row['first_name'][0] + '_' + row['last_name']
    u3 = row['first_name'][0] + '_' + row['last_name'][0]
    u4 = row['first_name'] + '_' + row['last_name'][0]
    return pd.Series([u1,u2,u3,u4], index=['u1','u2', 'u3','u4'])

df[['u1','u2', 'u3','u4']] = df.apply(gen_username, axis=1)

first_name middle_name last_name             u1       u2   u3         u4
0       John           D       Doe       John_Doe    J_Doe  J_D     John_D
1    Richard         NaN     Cohen  Richard_Cohen  R_Cohen  R_C  Richard_C
2      Molly      Claire     Smith    Molly_Smith  M_Smith  M_S    Molly_S
```

Answer (score 0):

First lets take out name columns

```
name_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('_name')]
```

Then we remove `NaN` for those columns

```
df[name_cols] = df[name_cols].fillna('')
```

Now we loop over and find all combinations. Fillowing code can be improved but you should get the idea

```py
from itertools import combinations

for set_size in range(2, len(name_cols) + 1): # we want combination of atleast 2 columns
    for subset in combinations(name_cols, set_size):
        key = '_'.join(subset)
        df[key] = ''
        for i in subset:
            df[key] = df[key] + ' ' + df[i]
        df[key] = df[key].str.strip()

>> print(df)

    name    first_name  middle_name last_name   first_name_middle_name  first_name_last_name    middle_name_last_name   first_name_middle_name_last_name
0   John Doe    John    D   Doe John D  John Doe    D Doe   John D Doe
1   Richard Cohen   Richard     Cohen   Richard Richard Cohen   Cohen   Richard Cohen
2   Molly Claire Smith  Molly   Claire  Smith   Molly Claire    Molly Smith Claire Smith    Molly Claire Smith
```